# AUI textboxlist - retrieve removed elements value

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui, liferay-aui, textboxlist

I am using Liferay 6.2 and want to retrieve the value of removed element from a [`Textboxlist`](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/Textboxlist.html) component. I have stored a list of values in a `hiddenInput` element, and I display the list in a `Textboxlist`. As I remove the element, I want to update the values stores in the hidden input element. But I do not know how to retrieve the removed element.

```
AUI().ready('aui-textboxlist-deprecated', function (A) {

    var source = A.one('#hiddenInput').val().split(',');

    var tagslist = new A.TextboxList({
        contentBox: '#demo',
        dataSource: source,
        matchKey: 'name',
        schema: {
            resultFields: ['key', 'name']
        },
        schemaType: 'json',
        typeAhead: true,
        width: 500
    }).render();

    var values = A.one('#hiddenInput').val().split(',');
    A.each(values, tagslist.add, tagslist);

    var updateHiddenInput = function (event) {

        //how to get the removed element?

    }

    tagslist.entries.after('remove', updateHiddenInput);
});
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you just need the label, then you can get it using `event.attrName`. If you need to work with the element, it is passed in `event.item.entry`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@jbalsas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681838/jbalsas) said in the comments:

> If you just need the label, then you can get it using `event.attrName`. If you need to work with the element, it is passed in `event.item.entry`.

So you should be able to do it like this:

```
var updateHiddenInput = function (event) {
    var hiddenInput = A.one('#hiddenInput');
    hiddenInput.val(hiddenInput.val() + ',' + event.item.entry); // or event.attrName
}
```